# Is there a nicer way to write this in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, nullable

This is my current code:

```
private val EXTRA_IS_REFRESHING = "IS_REFRESHING"
private var isRefreshing: Boolean = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    isRefreshing = if (savedInstanceState != null)        
        savedInstanceState!!.getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_REFRESHING, false) 
        else false
}
```

Is there a nicer way in Kotlin to write the last line?

Comment: The double bang !! shouldn’t be necessary due to smart casting after the null check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the way is just checking if result of nullable expression equals `true`:

```
isRefreshing = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_REFRESHING, false) == true
```

Or it may be **elvis** operator:

```
isRefreshing = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_REFRESHING, false) ?: false
```

As for me first snippet of code shows intention better, so I prefer it.

Comment: I actually prefer the 2nd snippet, to me it's clearer

Comment: The official style guide recommends the 1st version thou

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `if` completely in this case and assign `isRefreshing` to the conditional expression. Additionally, as mentioned by @s1m0nw1, smart-casting removes the need for `!!` or `?.`.

```
isRefreshing = savedInstanceState != null && 
               savedInstanceState.getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_REFRESHING, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you put more than one thing into saved state. In that case I use this:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // savedInstanceState is inferred non-null at this point, so no !!.
    isRefreshing = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_REFRESHING, isRefreshing)
} else {
    // First start.
}
```

But that's boring. Since we're in Kotlin, I can also imagine this:

```
savedInstanceState?.apply {
    isRefreshing = getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_REFRESHING, isRefreshing)
} ?: run {
    // First start.
}
```

or

```
savedInstanceState?.also {
    isRefreshing = it.getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_REFRESHING, isRefreshing)
} // ...
```